# How to bind in WPF with other Types?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm

I am playing around with WPF a bit. Here is the Code that does not work how i want it to.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding FilesToUpload}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Filename" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}">
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Uploaded" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Uploaded}">
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

The ItemsSource of ListView binds to a property of a class that returns a collection of this class.

```
public class FileInformation
        {
            public String FileName { get; set; }
            public ProgressBar Uploaded { get; set; }

            public FileInformation(String file)
            {
                FileName = file;
                Uploaded = new ProgressBar();
                Uploaded.Value = 8;
                Uploaded.BorderThickness = new System.Windows.Thickness(5);
            }
        }
```

The GridView from the xaml example above has two columns. One binds to the property FileName of class FileInformation and the other binds to Uploaded.

The problem is. The property Uploaded returns a ProgressBar but the content of the column that binds to Uploaded is a String (The returnvalue of ToString() Method of the ProgressBar i guess.).

Any suggestions how i can show the ProgressBar instead of a String?

Comment: Don't bind to the `ProgressBar` directly. I don't have access to the code at the moment but you should be able to recreate a progress bar by binding the width of a rectangle that's displayed in the cell to the `Value` of the progress bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This:

```
            <GridViewColumn Header="Progress">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>  
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ProgressBar Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Uploaded.Value}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>  
            </GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a very bad idea to have object inherited from FrameworkElement in bindings as sources.

Create a class that stores only datas for the ProgressBar defined in the view(xaml file).

```
public class ProgressBarViewModel : INotifiedPropertyChanged
{
    //add INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    //add Properties you want to bind to the ProgressBar
    ...

    //For example
    public double Value { //getter, setter methods. Raise PropertyChanged in setter if value changed}
   ...
}
```

Now, your Uploaded property should return an instance of the ProgressBarViewModel and you can bind this one to a ProgressBar in several ways.

I show you one way:

```
        <GridViewColumn Header="Uploaded">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=Uploaded.Value}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
```

**Note**: Uploaded in the binding is the property of your FileInformation class

Answer (score 0):

The binding of types is not supported in wpf it only bind ti properties. so if you need to bind a progress bar you need to place progressbase insteed of normal column. you also can create a custom view based on viewbase

see the example on below link.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/atc_avalon_team/archive/2006/04/28/585844.aspx